# Is it possible in Cake 3.0 to add a prefix in routing that isn't actually in the url?

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

What I want to achieve is to keep my baked controllers in src/Controller/, and to extend these for both my admin controllers (in src/Controller/Admin/) and my customer controllers (in src/Controller/Customer/). I have already achieved this for admins with:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

However, for customers I don't want /customer/ in the URL. Is this possible?

For example, http://example.org/users should use src/Controller/Customer/UsersController.php

Comment: I just cleaned up the prose to make it slightly more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect(
        '/:controller/:action/*',
        ['prefix' => 'customer'],
        ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']
   );
    $routes->connect(
        '/:controller/*',
        ['prefix' => 'customer'],
        ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']
    );
});
```